# (SOLVED!) Failed to resolve : com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0 and failed to resolve:com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0

Tags: android

Heres my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.phantomshadow.remindddddd"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
}
```

its solved.
i have bad knowledge before and dont know how to use stackoverflow XD
what to add, i just want to edit my question omg :(

Comment: Failed to answer question due to lack of [mcve](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no 25.3.0 yet AFAIK. 25.1.0 is the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**strong text**Change this code with same type gradle version..

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

Update Android SDK. It should install the required version of tools and after that should compile fine.